# Get single row out of duplicate columns based on other column

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Lets say I have this table / `IQueryable`:

```
+------+------+------+------------+-------------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | grouperCol | selectorCol |
+------+------+------+------------+-------------+
|    1 | John | Doe  | mail1      |             |
|    1 | John | Doe  | mail2      |           1 |
|    1 | John | Doe  | mail3_x    |             |
|    2 | Bob  | Ross | mail1      |           1 |
|    2 | Bob  | Ross | mail2_x    |             |
|    2 | Bob  | Ross | mail3_x    |             |
|    3 | Jane | Doe  | mail1      |             |
|    3 | Jane | Doe  | mail2      |             |
|    3 | Jane | Doe  | mail3      |             |
+------+------+------+------------+-------------+
```

And I want to get to this result:

```
+------+------+------+------------+-------------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | grouperCol | selectorCol |
+------+------+------+------------+-------------+
|    1 | John | Doe  | mail2      |           1 |
|    2 | Bob  | Ross | mail1      |           1 |
|    3 | Jane | Doe  | mail1      |             |
+------+------+------+------------+-------------+
```

Basically, I need to keep a single row, selecting the rows where selectorCol is not null OR the first one.

How do I do this in c#?

I'll probably need to do something like

```
var filtered =  context.table.GroupBy(x => x.col1).Where(...
```

But then I'm already stuck to write it short.

I could make a new list with a foreach or something but I guess it can be done with 1 single line?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for an SQL or Linq answer?

Comment: var filtered =  context.table.Where(x=> x.selectorCol != null).GroupBy(x => x.col1), this way you can get all the registers that are not null, i didnt understand your OR condition..

Comment: Use an `OrderBy` on each group to sort the non-null `selectorCol` to be first, then select the first row in each group.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it based on only `col1` then:

```
var result = context.table.GroupBy(x => x.col1)
    .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault(x =>selectorCol != null)??g.First());
```

for firstname and lastname (`col1`, `col2`);

```
var result = context.table.GroupBy(x => {x.col1, x.col2})
    .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault(x =>selectorCol != null)??g.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your one-liner:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.col1, (k, g) => g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.selectorCol == 1) ?? g.FirstOrDefault())
```

But, I am curious what kind of db query this will generate. Likely, the group reducing will be done in memory.

Edit: Apparently the above linq generates a query with subqueries. It would be better to split it into 2 methods to avoid performance issue:

```
.OrderBy(x => x.selectorCol == null)
.GroupBy(x => x.col1, (k, g) => g.FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: In LINQ to SQL this generated a very strange query that had a CASE with two similar conditions, one with `NOT EXISTS` and one with `NOT NOT EXISTS`, and then had to pull the answers with additional queries, one per group.

Comment: @NetMage Ouf, subqueries. I am surprised that linq2sql managed to convert that part.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I need to keep a single row, selecting the rows where selectorCol is not null OR the first one.

You didn't explicitly say so, but I assume that if two Rows have the same `Col1`, that they also have the same `Col2` and `Col3`

**Requirement** Given a sequence of `MyRows`, create a resulting sequence, created from Groups of `MyRows` with the same value for `Col1`. From every Group I want the first element that has a non-null value of `SelectorCol`

If you write the requirement precisely, it doesn't seem very difficult. The only problem is: what is the *first element of a group*? Is that the one with the lowest index?

As GroupBy doesn't guarantee anything about keeping the original order, we have to remember the index of the original items.

- Do a Select where you remember the index of the original item
- Then make Groups of items with the same value for `Col1`
- From every Group keep the elements that have a non-null value for SelectorCol
- Then take the one with the lowest index.

.

```
// first remember the original index
var result = myRows.Select( (row, index) => new
{
    Index = index
    Row = row,
}
// Then make groups of rows with same value for Col1
.GroupBy(selectResult => selectResult.Row.Col1,

// Parameter resultSelector: get the key of each group (= common Col1 value)
// and all rows that have this Col1 value
// keep only the groupElements that have a non-null value for SelectorCol
(col1, rowsWithThisCol1) => rows.WithThisCol1
     .Where(groupElement => groupElement.Row.SelectorCol != null)

     // from the remaining rows, keep the one with the lowest index
     .OrderBy(groupElement => groupElement.Index)

     // we don't need the Index anymore, select only the Row
     .Select(groupElement => groupElement.Row)

     // and keep the first:
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Although this one works, it is a bit of a waste, to order all group elements, if you only want the one with the lowest index. Use Aggregate if you want to enumerate only once. So instead of OrderBy:

```
.Aggregate((groupElementWithLowestIndex, groupElement) =>
    // if the index of groupElement is lower,
    // then that element becomes the one with the lowest index

    (groupElement.Index < groupElementWithLowestIndex.Index) ?
     groupElement : groupElementWithLowestIndex)

// result: the one and only groupElement with the lowest index
// note: you are certain that no group is empty! So there is always one with lowest index
// get rid of the index, keep only the Row
.Row;
```